# How to use EXCEL to display SQL Server 2005 Query Result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, spreadsheet

I have 50 databases in SQL Server 2005 and each database has the same table that I use to pull data from.
I wrote SQL with cursor in it so that it loops through all the database specified.
I got the result in the 50 different result panes.
My requirement is to import and display the results in 50 different sheets in the excel spreadsheet.
My question:
Is there a way in the excel that I can use so that I can display the results in 50 different sheets automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can achieve this by using VBA. I'd record a macro where you import one of these tables into one (newly added) worksheet. You can then change this newly recorded macro to create all sheets and queries automatically.

**Edit:**
To get started, you can read through the resources provided in the threads:
[How to get started with Visual Basic for Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020841/how-to-get-started-with-visual-basic-for-applications) or [Where do I get started with VBA and macros programming in Word 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210286/where-do-i-get-started-with-vba-and-macros-programming-in-word-2007) (which actually also links to a video).

Comment: Hi MP24, Thank you. Could you please provide me some examples or relevant tutorials so that I can follow it and accomplish my aim.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary table

```
create table #t (id int, col1 varchar, col2 varchar)
```

In your cursor you can insert data from 50 different databases into it

```
insert #t(id, col1, col2)
select id, col1, col2
from SomeDatabase.dbo.tt
```

And then select **all data** from it **to one pane**.

```
select * from #t
```

Don't let data manipulate you. Manipulate it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script a lot to spew out MSSQL Data to an Excel sheet. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=database;Server=sql;Driver={SQL Server}"

'conn.Open connString
' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection and execute.
'LOOP OVER SHEETS WITH DIFFERENT TABLES
conn.Open sConnString
For i = 1 To 50

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE")

' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
    Sheets(i).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If
Next i
'END LOOP
' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub